# selecting with UIButton and moving a specific model data with segue

Tags: swift, object, segue

I am new to swift and new to programming in general. I am building a quiz app. I want to select a topic in a TopicViewController and move to a new Quizviewcontroller that will display the question and answer choices. I have multiple question bank that I believe are objects of a class Question. I am able to move to the QuizViewConctroller with segue but unable to select the Question bank based on the topic UI button selected.
I have tried and spent days trying to figure this out. I have looked at similar posts in SO. I have posted this question before but did not get any reply. I would really appreciate if someone could help. I don't know how else to proceed...

TopicsViewController:

```
import UIKit

class TopicsViewController: UIViewController, ReturnToTopicVCDelegate {

    func goToTopicVC() {}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func goToQuestionsVCWhenPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueToQuestionVC", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "segueToQuestionVC" {
            let quizVC = segue.destination as! QuizViewController
            quizVC.delegate = self
        }
    }

}
```

QuizViewController:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

protocol ReturnToTopicVCDelegate {
    func goToTopicVC()
}

class QuizViewController: UIViewController {

    var delegate: ReturnToTopicVCDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var optionAButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionBButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionCButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionDButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionEButton: UIButton!
    //outlets for the progress
    @IBOutlet weak var questionCounter: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    var allQuestions = QuestionBank()
    var selectedAnswer: Int = 0 // answer selected by the subject
    var questionNumber: Int = 0
    var score: Int = 0

    @IBAction func answerPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if sender.tag == selectedAnswer {
            print("correct answer")
            sender.backgroundColor = .green
            score += 1
        } else {
            print("wrong")
            sender.backgroundColor = .red
            print("\(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].correctAnswer)")

            //the following two lines change the right answer button to green using the tag value of the button

            let correctAnswerButton = view.viewWithTag(selectedAnswer) as? UIButton
            correctAnswerButton?.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
    }

    @IBAction func GoToNextQuestion(_ sender: UIButton) {
        questionNumber += 1
        nextQuestion()
    }

    func nextQuestion() {

        if questionNumber <= allQuestions.list.count - 1 {
            questionLabel.text = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].question
            questionImageView.image = UIImage(named: (allQuestions.list[questionNumber].questionImage))

            optionAButton.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionA, for: .normal)
            optionBButton.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionB, for: .normal)
            optionCButton.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionC, for: .normal)
            optionDButton.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionD, for: .normal)
            optionEButton.setTitle(allQuestions.list[questionNumber].optionE, for: .normal)

            selectedAnswer = allQuestions.list[questionNumber].correctAnswer
            updateUI()

        } else {

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Great!", message: "Do you want to start over?", preferredStyle: .alert)

            let restartAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Restart", style: .default) { (UIAlertAction) in
                self.restartQuiz()
            }

            alert.addAction(restartAction)
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func updateUI() {
        scoreLabel.text = "score: \(score)"
        questionCounter.text = "\(questionNumber + 1)/\(allQuestions.list.count)"
    }

    func restartQuiz() {
        score = 0
        questionNumber = 0
        nextQuestion()
    }

    @IBAction func goBackToTopicsVC(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.goToTopicVC()
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

The Questions are in this format

```
import Foundation

class QuestionBank {

    var list = [Question]()

    init() {

        let skyColorQuestion = Question(questionText: “What is the color of sky?", image: "sky", choiceA: "blue", choiceB: "black", choiceC: "yellow", choiceD: "pink", choiceE: "None of the above", answer: 1)
        let whatQuestion = Question(questionText: “what…?”, image: "image", choiceA: "x", choiceB: "y", choiceC: "z", choiceD: "m", choiceE: "None of the above", answer: 3)

        list.append(skyColorQuestion)
        list.append(whatQuestion)
    }
}
```

[Navigation Pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQm0l.png)

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYGCv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add the data are not correct in this way. My recommendation you can use a Realm, sqLite, CoreData or FireBase.